# ProcessBuilder doesn't recognise embedded command

Tags: java, terminal, processbuilder

I have a method

```
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(this.cmd);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            final Process process = processBuilder.start();
            try (final BufferedReader reader =
                         new BufferedReader(
                                 new InputStreamReader(
                                         process.getInputStream()
                                 )
                         )
            ) {
                while (reader.ready()) {
                    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
                }
                process.waitFor(this.timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        } catch (final Exception exc) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Terminal command execution exception", exc);
        }
```

This method takes cmd(array of strings) from Constructor and then executes it. This is the value of cmd

```
new String[]{"cat","$(cat /home/Downloads/tmp/aqnYtUSVFp.txt)",">","/home/Downloads/hello.ts"}
```

So the whole command is looks like this `cat $(cat home/Downloads/tmp/aqnYtUSVFp.txt) > /home/Downloads/hello.ts`
It works fine if I run it within terminal , but ProcessBuilder shows me the following error

```
cat: '$(cat /home/Downloads/aqnYtUSVFp.txt)': No such file or directory
cat: '>': No such file or directory
cat: /home/Downloads/hello.ts: No such file or directory
```

What did I miss . Why ProccBuilder doesn't recognize this command ?

Comment: Handling sub shells and redirection is the job for a shell such as sh or bash. `cat does not know how to  do that. You probably want to execute `/bin/sh` with appropriate arguments.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö great idea I will do it and post my answer

Comment: ProcessBuilder (since j7) _can_ handle simple redirections, but with method calls not tokens in the command; see the javadoc. It (still) can't handle shell-type pipes, or variables or command substitution -- although this particular one could be replaced by `new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename))) .trim() .split("[ \t\n]+")`

Comment: Are you simply experimenting with class `ProcessBuilder` in order to understand how it works? Or are you trying to copy file `aqnYtUSVFp.txt` to file `hello.ts`?